# About the definition of the dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

**DEFINITION: The dimension of a space is the number of vectors in every basis.**

This is the definition of dim from *Introduction to Linear Algebra 4th* by Strang.

I have a question here. A vector in $R^n$ is belong to n-dim space.  When we talk about a plane, we refer to the 2-dim subspace in 3-dim space or just the 2-dim space? If we agree with the former, doesn't it belong 3-dim space? So why is the statement **The dimension of a space is the number of vectors in every basis** valid?

I think it a bit difficult because of the language, haha, thanks if you help!

Comment: I am not sure what you're describing.  Are you talking about the two-dimensional $xy$-plane within the three dimensional $xyz$-space?  If so, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is *not* inside of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the vectors have different numbers of entries) even though $\mathbb{R}^3$ has many two-dimensional planes (containing the origin) inside it which are *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Here's an example to consider.  Let $U$ be the set of all vectors $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $x_1 = x_2 = x_3$ (in other words, all three components of $x$ are equal).  Then, $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, and the dimension of $U$ is $1$.  (Can you find a basis for $U$?)

Comment: @littleO I know what you mean, but $x_1$ is belong to 3-dim.. So why does the dim is one?

Comment: @standerQiu Before I answer that, maybe forget about "dimension" for a minute, and tell me this: can you give me a basis for the subspace $U$?

Comment: @littleO Yep, a basis for subspace $U$ is $x_1$

Comment: @standerQiu What is $x_1$?  I don't understand what you mean.  I was expecting you to tell me that a basis for $U$ is the set $\mathcal B = \{ (1,1,1) \}$, or something like that.

Comment: @littleO You say that $x_1=x_2=x_3$ , so the three vectors are linearly dependent, the only pivot column is $x_1$ ,$ x_2$ or $x_3$, and the basis of **U** is one of the former three.

Comment: $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \Bbb{R}$. They are scalars, not vectors. $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is the vector.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Oh...Yep!!! Thx

Comment: @littleO I am wrong, the $x_i$ is scalar.. The basis of $U$ is the set of $(c,c,c)$, c is any real number. Any two vectors of $U$ are linear dependent, so the dim is 1

Comment: Let's just be very concrete and give one single example of a basis for $U$.  The set $\mathcal B = \{ (1,1,1) \}$ is a basis for $U$.  And since this basis has one element, the dimension of $U$ is $1$.

Comment: @littleO In your opinion, the *element* is vector, not the number of the component, so the concept of dim is linked to the vector instead of *scalar*?

Comment: Yes, assuming I understand you correctly.  Here's another example.  Let $W = \{ x = (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x_1 = x_2\}$.  (Note that $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$ are scalars, and $x$ is a vector.)  So $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.  Can you give me a basis of $W$?

Comment: @littleO Yep, (1,1,1), (1,1,2) or other..

Comment: Yes, that works.  Since a basis is a set of vectors, I would express your answer using set notation: the set $\{ (1,1,1), (1,1,2) \}$ is a basis for $W$.  Since this basis has two elements, $W$ has dimension $2$.  (By the way, another basis for $W$ is $\{ (1,1,0), (0,0,1) \}$.)

Comment: @littleO I used to think that a vector in $R^n$ is n-dim, actually is 1-dim. The shape of it is like the vector in 1-dim. But actually, they are different, because the former has n *coordinates*, the latter has only one. Is that right?

Comment: If you are talking about $\Bbb{R}^n$, then yes, all of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is n-dimensional. However, if you have a basis of one vector from $\Bbb{R}^n$, then you simply have a line or a one-dimensional subspace. You are right in that these two are different because the former has a basis of n vectors while the latter has only one vector in its basis.

Comment: @standerQiu Although the word "dimension" is used loosely sometimes, strictly speaking it is only a *subspace* or a *vector space* that can have a dimension.  If you tell me that a particular subspace has dimension 2, I know exactly what you mean.  But, if you tell me that a particular vector has dimension 3, or that a particular vector has dimension 1, then I would have to object that this statement is meaningless, because the "dimension of a vector" has never been defined (and is not a standard term in math).  Only a subspace or a vector space can have a dimension, not a vector.

Comment: @littleO Er..Yep! I know what you mean.. Oh.. Sometimes I make mistakes in small concepts. What I suppose to mean is the same **shape** but actually different in **nature**..( Sorry for the mistakes in the concept)

Comment: @littleO Thank you very much! At first, I feel that you are a teacher when you ask me about the concept. Aha! You actually are!! UCLA !!! You are so nice and great! I want to say " mo bai" to you in Chinese!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That definition isn't worded correctly. It should be "The dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors in every basis **of that space, containing only vectors from that space**."

Therefore, when we talk about a plane, which is a 2-dimensional subspace in a 3-dimensional vector space, the bases of vectors only from that plane only have 2 vectors in them, so it can still be 2-dimensional without contradicting that the original vector space had 3 vectors in their bases.

Let's take an example. $\Bbb{R}^3$  will be our 3-dimensional vector space and $\{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 \mid z=0\}$ will be our 2-dimensional vector space. (Our 2-dimensional subspace is the same as the $xy$-plane.)

It is very easy to show that the following is a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$:
$$\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\}$$

However, in our two-dimensional subspace, $z$ is always $0$. Therefore, the vector $(0, 0, 1)$ is not part of our basis because it has a non-zero $z$-coordinate. $(0, 0, 1)$ is not in the plane, so it can not be in the plane's basis. The other two vectors are, however, because there is no restriction on the $x$ and $y$-coordinates. Therefore, the plane has the following basis:

$$\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\}$$

Thus, the whole vector space has a basis with three elements, but the plane is only a subset of the vector space, so it only contains a smaller basis. This is how a 2-dimensional subspace can be inside of a 3-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Aha, I agree with the first paragraph. I still have a question: why a vector (1,0,0) is one-dim instead of 3-dim? Does't the (1,0,0) belong to 3-dim?  In my opinion, *the dim is the number of components of the vector* ( Though it might be wrong)

Comment: No, the dimension is not the number of components of the vector. If you have just $\{(1, 0, 0)\}$ as your basis, then your basis only has one vector, so that vector space generated by that basis has a dimensionality of 1. That subspace, the subspace $(a, 0, 0)$ for all $a \in \Bbb{R}$, is a one-dimensional subspace of the original vector space, which is $\Bbb{R}^3$. That original vector space is found by the number of components of the vector, but the dimensionality of the subspace is not.

Comment: In conclusion, the concept of *component* is totally wrong? But when we say the 1-dim space, what are we talking about, a point or 1-dim subspace in higher dim space?

Comment: When we are talking about a one-dimensional space, we could be talking about just $\Bbb{R}$ or we could be talking about a one-dimensional subspace in a higher dimensional space. Also, some vectors are polynomials or elements of a field extension. They aren't always tuples like $(1, 2, 3)$, sometimes they are things like $\alpha^2+\alpha+2$. Vectors don't always have "components" and the number of components isn't related to the dimensionality.

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much!!